# Create AlertDialog using inside layout of a xml

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to create a alert dialog using a layout which is in a xml. I tried this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.id.optionsmenu, null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.setView(v).create();

    dialog.show();
```

It does not work. optionsmenu is the layout that i want to use to create alert dialog. Can i set alert dialog view to this inner layout ?

[here](http://i57.tinypic.com/mtpb14.png) is the image's url . You can see the layout that i want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really know how you expect your dialog to look like but you should create it like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         dialog.setTitle("");

         //to use a view inside the xml (i.e. a button)

         Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.optionsmenu);

dialog.show();
```

Note that you were trying to inflate not the layout but the view (R.id.optionsmenu) it should have been (R.layout.activity_main)

alertDialog.builder is used to create a dialog without using a xml layout

Comment: this creates dialog that has the main activity view. but i want just the inside layout. Actually, i want layout position in xml because when i use inside layout, i do not need to resize the dialog to put the orjinal point.